# multer file-upload doesn't work with node-windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-services, multer, node-windows

I am trying to upload picture files, using `multer`.
This is is my code:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
  // An error occurred when uploading
  conole.log(err);
  return;
}

// Everything went fine
var data = Object.assign({picture: req.file && req.file.filename}, req.body);
db.create('devices', data)
.then(function(data){
    res.render('msg', {msg: 'Added device '+ data[0]});
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

});

});
```

However, when I try to run the server from the command-line `node app.js`, everything is working as expected. But when I'm running it from A windows service, using `node-windows`, it doesn't seem to work, while I don't get any errors. (Meaning the picture file name is actually recorded in the database, but the file doesn't upload.
is it maybe a destination issue? if so, I will provide my destination code:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './public/uploads/',
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null,  file.originalname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `destination` to a directory is for sure writable by all users? It could be a permission issue or that the relative `destination` is not being resolved correctly if the cwd is different for services.

Comment: Thanks. The `destination` directory is writable for all users. But I am not sure how I can figure out the cwd for the window-service. I will try to use `path`.

Comment: But in any case, why wouldn't I get an error?

Comment: `process.cwd()` should return the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks, will try it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove this line from your code

```
destination: './public/uploads/',
```

and add this code

```
destination: __dirname+'../../../uploads',
```

this will work both mac OS and windows